# mysql: how to update automatically TimeStamp when a field has been updated

Tags: mysql, timestamp, sql-update

I have a simple DB-table with few fields for articles database among  that is a TimeStamp containing the  time of the last update made on the article.

I use "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Problem is that I want to update  only if some fields of this record have changed, not all.

i.e. For each article, I have a field giving the number of time the article has been read by visitors.  must not be updated after each web visit... only if I change the title, authors, etc...

Ideally with a nice mysql command...

---

I have coded the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `actu_lastupdate_date` BEFORE UPDATE ON `actuality`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    if NEW.title <> OLD.title OR NEW.chapeau = OLD.chapeau OR NEW.content = OLD.content
    then
        SET NEW.LastUpdate_date = current_timestamp;
    end if;
END
```

it seems that even if another record field is changing, the Timestamp is updated. There should be something bad somewhere.
I'll look into it

Comment: You could try using [Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)...

Comment: thanks. Now trying to understand how this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a trigger to add the  timestamp on updates

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER actu_lastupdate_date AFTER UPDATE on actuality
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if (NEW.title <> OLD.title 
         OR NEW.chapeau <> OLD.chapeau 
         OR NEW.content <> OLD.content)
        AND (NEW.other_column = OLD.other_column 
         OR NEW.other_column2 = OLD.other_column2)
    then
        SET NEW.LastUpdate_date = current_timestamp;
    end if;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this will set a new timestamp on the field timestamp_column of table your_table each time there is an update of the row IF col1 or col2 or col3 do no change ?

As I need to update the timestamp only if some fields have changed, I need to change the if then condition: if (NEW.col1<>OLD.col1) OR (NEW.col2<>OLD.col2) then SET NEW.timestamp_column = current_timestamp;

Comment: @ThomasP: Change `AFTER UPDATE` to `BEFORE UPDATE`

Comment: I updated again. The logic is: Only set timestamp if any of the fields `title, chapeau content` are changed and none of the fields `other_column, othercolumn2` are changed.

Comment: That sound's good. in others words, if the field "nb_reading" is changing for example, timestamp should not be updated as this is not par of the if-then condition ?